# Unicode Encoding and Decoding

Tags: android, unicode

I want an android code or algorithum which will accept a Marathi text as input and convert the marathi text into unicode code. Also reconvert the unicode into marathi text.

i tried some code like:-

string marathi = "मी लाइक आहे";

UnicodeEncoding ue = new UnicodeEncoding(true,true);

string s1 = BitConverter.ToString(ue.GetBytes(marathi.ToCharArray())).Replace("-", "");

but this code is not working in case of android.

Help me as soon as possible. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Convert a string to unicode -

```
public String toUnicode(String text) {
    String txt = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        Log.d("Unicode", (int) text.charAt(i));
        txt = txt + "\\" + text.charAt(i);
    }
return txt;
}
```

To convert unicode into string, use -

```
public String toString(String uni){

    String tt = "";

    String[] parts = uni.split("\\");

    for(String x:parts){
        x = "\\" + x;
        char un = x.toCharArray()[0];
        tt = text + un;

    }
return tt;
}
```